# jquery-visible - Visible whole element

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page where user should show his skill and bars grow when the user loads that slide (impress.js). For that I'm using [jquery-visible](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible) plugin. So this function works great when I switch between two distant slides, but when they are near each other, one part of the skill page is "visible" and bars load their full size early.
Here is the code that I used for my bars:

```
var win = jQuery(window);
var allMods = jQuery(".skill"); //.skill is container

allMods.each(function(i, el) {
  if (jQuery(el).visible(true)) {                                           
    jQuery("span.bar.line1").animate({ width: 80 }, 3000, function() { });
   } 
});
```

I hardly make this work:) But can you help to make it TRUE only if it's whole div visible?

Answer (score 0):

I remowed whole jquery-visible code and I used addEventListener for entering that slide (div).

> document.getElementById("slideID").addEventListener
>                                                         ("impress:stepenter", function (event) {
>
> ```
>       // Code for step enter
> ```
>
> }, false);